# Vite + React: Rollup unable to resolve issue on netlify and vercel

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel, netlify

I'm facing build issues while trying to deploy me vite + react on vercel or netlify. The issues are something like [vite]: Rollup issue unable to resolve ./src/main.jsx .
and sometimes other components as well.
This issue most of the time gets fixed when I transfer the code to some other github repository.
The build works perfectly on my windows local machine every time.

Is there anyone else who has ever had same experience?
Can anyone please help me with this issue as I can't always keep changing the repos when working in collaboration.

I have searched the entire internet and can't find any solution.

I tried add the aliases but no success. My vite.config file is default.